# Angular 13 customize root path for lazy loaded chunks

Tags: angular, angular12, angular13

I have multi - modular Angular 13 application, where modules are loaded using lazy - loading. The problem is that generated Angular files like main.[hash].js, pollyfils.[hash].js and runtime.[hash].js are located NOT at the site root. The structure looks like following:

```
/index.html
  /mysitefolder/main.f29052602897eb02.js
  /mysitefolder/styles.755cfc65dad8627d.css
  /mysitefolder/polyfills.eca354b64e370005.js
  /mysitefolder/runtime.54752149a889ba60.js
  /mysitefolder/815.d3bd01384abd247c.js
```

The Angular.json file has following setting:

```
"outputPath": "../public/mysitefolder"
```

When application runs, it tries to load the chunk file `815.d3bd01384abd247c.js` from the application root, not from the it's actual location, obviously chunk load fails. How to fix this? Is there any setting to tell Angular to load chunks for lazy - loaded modules from the specific `/mysitefolder/` location?

Comment: Is your angular.json at the same directory level as mysitefolder?

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov mysitefolder is located at the build target or output directory but angular.json is located in the project directory. Simply saying they are in completly separate locations.